# react native android error

Tags: android, react-native, exception

I developed an application in react native

It run on ios perfectly
but in android it has below error:

> E/unknown:React: Exception in native call
>
> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method
>   'java.util.Iterator java.util.List.iterator()' on a null object
>   reference
>                                                                                at
>   com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.processPackage(ReactInstanceManager.java:952)
>                                                                                at
>   com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.createReactContext(ReactInstanceManager.java:891)
>                                                                                at
>   com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.access$600(ReactInstanceManager.java:104)
>                                                                                at
>   com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager$ReactContextInitAsyncTask.doInBackground(ReactInstanceManager.java:218)
>                                                                                at
>   com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager$ReactContextInitAsyncTask.doInBackground(ReactInstanceManager.java:197)
>                                                                                at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:304)
>                                                                                at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
>                                                                                at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
>                                                                                at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
>                                                                                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)

how I can fix this problem? why this problem occurred?

Comment: share your code with question

Comment: there might be some dependency missing on your android project

Comment: Did you read the error? `Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.util.Iterator java.util.List.iterator()' on a null object`, you are trying to iterate a list that is null

Comment: @KhalilKhalaf yeah. I read the error, but it's work perfectly on ios and I didn't write any extra code for android. this error occurred in native method and I can't change that

Comment: @bennygenel I didn't think because it build successful

Comment: @NileshRathod I didn't write any code for android. It's a react native method and i can't change them

Comment: I think iterator iterates the react components. some external component you are using is not inked correctly if you ask my opinion.

Comment: I found the solution, thanks all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I change RNSpinkitPackage class like below and it has worked in android perfectly like ios:

```
public class RNSpinkitPackage implements ReactPackage{
@Override
public List<NativeModule> createNativeModules(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
    return Collections.emptyList();
}

@Override
public List<Class<? extends JavaScriptModule>> createJSModules() {
    return Collections.emptyList();
}

@Override
public List<ViewManager> createViewManagers(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
    List<ViewManager> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(new RNSpinkit(reactContext));
    return list;
}
```

}